# Is there a way to convert a d3 rollup created with two keys to a flat array-of-objects structure?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I came across this situation in a project with d3 recently. First, here is what I am working with:

```
myRollup = d3.rollup(data,
              a => a.length,
              d => d.category,  // key1
              d => d.city)      // key2
```

Below is the typical output of `d3.rollup` when given **2 keys**. It produces this nested `Map` structure that is `myRollup`:

```
Map(3) {
  "television" => Map(2) {
    "city1" => 3673
    "city2" => 6712
  }
  "web" => Map(2) {
    "city1" => 124
    "city2" => 876
  }
  "film" => Map(2) {
    "city1" => 243
    "city2" => 678
  }
}
```

My end goal is to create a stacked bar chart with this, so I want to convert this to a neat array of objects form like so:

```
const data = [
  {category: "television", city1: 3673, city2: 6712},
  {category: "web", city1: 124, city2: 876},
  {category: "film", city1: 243, city2: 678}
];
```

I have tried using `Array.from` (and its 2nd argument `mapFn`) to try and convert this to the ^ above form. In conjunction with the spread operator `...`, I am able to get close but not exactly where I need to be. In effect, I need something like this =>

```
Array.from(myRollup, ([category, cities]) => ({
  category: category,
  <each city>: <city's count>   // each of cities.keys(): each of cities.values()
}));
```

Something like this impossible `[...cities.keys()]: [cities.values()]` both spread vertically somehow. Definitely feel like I'm missing something simple. I have my end result now, but is there a nice ***declarative*** way to do this (as opposed to manually constructing the final structure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be the wonderful `Object.fromEntries` (which takes an iterable including a Map) I had totally forgotten about!

This is exactly what I need:

```
Array.from(myRollup, ([category, cities]) => ({
  category: category,
  ...Object.fromEntries(cities) // maps each of cities.keys() to each of cities.values()
}));
```